# Remove property in overriden class

Tags: html, css

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="external_1.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="external_2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="local.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="class1 class2">Some text</span>
</body>
```

external_1.css

```
.class1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

external_2.css

```
body .class2 {
    color: green;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

local.css

```
body .class2 {
    color: remove-property;
}
```

`external_1.css` and `external_2.css` files are external and I can't change those. All I can do is to override them with `local.css`

**My question is: How can I override the class `.class2` and remove the property `color` in a way that the property from `.class1` is applied to the `span`, to in the end the properties on `span` would be:**

```
{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**Edit:** I don't know what the property value in `.class1` is. Maybe it's dynamic, I shouldn't set `color: red;` in `local.css`.

Comment: Can you load 2 before 1?

Comment: @Mooseman, I edited the question. Order of the external files would not affect it, because `.class2` is more specific than `.class1`

Comment: could you describe your situation a bit more? What's happening? what color *do* you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redefine color. CSS is not dynamic, as you are saying you have no control on both external css. There is no option so you can use external_1.css's .class1 color value. If you try to call external_1.css after external_2.css, still external_2.css class will be preferred because it has deeper element declaration...

```
body .class2{color:green;}
```

while in external_1.css only class declaration...

```
.class1{color:red;}
```

Comment: Wow, so did I wrote something else? cuz I got -1 for my answer and I wrote the same thing 30 mins back

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** : As you edited in your question, it changes the entire meaning of what you have asked. CSS is not a dynamic language hence it cannot decide on its own or even conditionally of what to pick and what not to. You need to specify the properties for each rule.

Things you should do in such cases is to use CSS Preprocessors which are capable of conditional CSS rules and can nest the rules inside other or you need to change your dirty way of tackling these issues by getting rid of such confusing way of declaring classes.

Or you can use JS at last to tweak up the markup on the run.

---

This is where **specificity** comes handy, all you need to do is to write a rule in your `local.css` file which is more specific than your previous loaded CSS files.

```
.wrapper span.class1.class2 {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kfs07t6o/)

Lets **assume** that you have SOME kind of wrapper element with a `class` or an `id` on it, all you need to do is to write a specific selector to override the color of your `span` element from `green` to `red`.

Surely you can use things like `!important` but I suggest you not to use so because later it will give you more specificity issues so keep it simple and write a specific selector in your `local.css` stylesheet.

Also whats the great thing about this is that you won't have to worry anymore how your stylesheets are loaded and in what order till you have a specific rule which will override the base ones.

Last but not the least this will target all the `span` elements having both the classes nested under an element with a `class` of `.wrapper` so if you want to be more specific simply address the only `span` you want to target. Surely you can use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` to select the `span` precisely.

Comment: Please take a look at the note after editing my answer.

Comment: @AlinRoman That edit is unclear to me. Please explain in detail

Comment: I want `span` to have the property `color` specified in `external_1.css`, not the same property specified in `local.css`. This is because I can't be sure that in `external_1.css` the `color` is `red`.

Comment: @AlinRoman: could you not remove your `class="class2"` and add the other properties to `.anotherClass` and make it to `class="class2 anotherClass"`?

Comment: @jbutler483 I can't be sure what other properties both classes have declared as the external files may change over time and I can't control that.

Comment: @AlinRoman then CSS is not a dynamic language that it can decide and inherit specific property on its own, you need to specify and browser will adapt that, will edit my answer.

Comment: @AlinRoman: So how *are* you deciding which `color` was the initial one?

Comment: @jbutler483 haha it is confusing, not possible with css unless he swaps the declared order using JS